# How can I style autocomplete result

Tags: javascript, css, forms, autocomplete, css-selectors

I want to apply some **CSS style** on the *autocomplete* result of the input type text element. How can I select the *autocomplete* result using CSS selectors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is a `:-webkit-autofill` selector on input field, but support is a little bit less. read more at here: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:-webkit-autofill)